# Getting message Review the SQL script to be applied on the database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am getting the following message while creating a stored procedure in MySQL Workbench:

"Review the SQL script to be applied on the database"

I have several tables inside the database but the stored procedure I am writing will be
used only for one table. Since, the SQL script of stored procedure is gonna apply on the whole database, I am wondering if it's gonna affect other tables as well? I don't want other tables to get disturbed because of this script.

Please provide your inputs as I am doing this for the first time.

Question #2:

Why do I see "DELIMITER $$" as the first statement while creating a routine before the following statement?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `mydatabase`.`myfirstroutine` ()

BEGIN
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) MySQL Workbench offers the option to review the generated SQL script before it is sent to the server. This way you can check it for possible problems.

2) The `DELIMITER` command is usually necessary to switch the current delimiter that ends a single statement (which is by default a semicolon) to something else because the stored procedure code itself needs the semicolon to separate individual commands. However the sp code must be sent as a whole to the server.

A few more details: the `DELIMITER` keywword is a client keyword only, that means the server doesn't know it and doesn't need it. It's an invention for clients to properly separate sql commands before sending them to the server (you cannot send a list of commands to a server, only individual statements).

In MySQL Workbench however, especially in the object editors where you edit e.g. the sp text, adding the DELIMITER command is essentially nonsense, because there's only this sp code, hence nothing to separate. This might disappear in future version but for now just ignore it.